# Why Am I getting Cannot read property 'firstItemIndex' of undefined?

Tags: angular

I have this code in my html

```
<form [formGroup]="this.participantSearchService.searchParticipantForm"
    (ngSubmit)="this.participantSearchService.onSubmit()">

    <div class="formsTitle">
        <span style="color:#fff; font-size: 15px">{{ this.appService.title}}</span>
    </div>
    <table class="label" width="100%">
        <colgroup class="label-td" width="130">
        </colgroup>
        <colgroup width="380">
        </colgroup>
        <colgroup class="label-td" width="130">
        </colgroup>
        <colgroup width="380">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>جهة المشارك </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select formControlName="participantLocation">
                        <option value="">الكل</option>
                        <option value="1">من داخل الدولة</option>
                        <option value="2">من خارج الدولة</option>
                    </select>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <label>نوع المشارك </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select formControlName="participantType">
                        <option value="">الكل</option>
                        <option value="1">الشيوخ</option>
                        <option value="2">الجماعة</option>
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> الاسم </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="participantName">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label> الجنسية </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select formControlName="participantNationality">
                        <option value="">الكل</option>
                        <option value="1">الإمارات</option>
                        <option value="2">السعودية</option>
                        <option value="3">سلطنة عمان</option>
                        <option value="4">البحرين</option>
                        <option value="5">الكويت</option>
                        <option value="6">قطر</option>
                        <option value="7">أخرى</option>
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> جهة إصدار الهوية </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select formControlName="IDCountry">
                        <option value="">الكل</option>
                        <option value="1">الإمارات</option>
                        <option value="2">السعودية</option>
                        <option value="3">سلطنة عمان</option>
                        <option value="4">البحرين</option>
                        <option value="5">الكويت</option>
                        <option value="6">قطر</option>
                        <option value="7">أخرى</option>
                    </select>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <label> مكان التسجيل </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select formControlName="registrationPlace"
                        (change)="this.participantSearchService.onRegistrationPlaceIdChanged($event)">
                        <option value="">الكل</option>
                        <option value="1">الوثبة</option>
                        <option value="2">المرموم</option>
                        <option value="5">سويحان</option>
                        <option value="6">السوان</option>
                        
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> رقم الهوية </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="number" formControlName="ID">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label> الميدان </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <select formControlName="center">
                        <option value="">الكل</option>
                        <option [value]="center.CenterId"
                            *ngFor="let center of this.participantSearchService.FilteredCentersList">
                            {{center.CenterName}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> الهاتف </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input formControlName="phoneNo" type="number">

                </td>

                <td>
                    <label> العنوان </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input formControlName="address" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> من تاريخ التسجيل </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input formControlName="fromRegistrationDate" type="date">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label> إلى تاريخ التسجيل </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input formControlName="toRegistrationDate" type="date">
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> من تاريخ الإنتهاء </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input formControlName="fromExpiryDate" type="date">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <label> إلى تاريخ الإنتهاء </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input formControlName="toExpiryDate" type="date">
                </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>

                <td>
                    <label> جهة إصدار بطاقة مشارك </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select formControlName="cardCountry">
                        <option value="">الكل</option>
                        <option value="1">الإمارات</option>
                        <option value="2">السعودية</option>
                        <option value="3">سلطنة عمان</option>
                        <option value="4">البحرين</option>
                        <option value="5">الكويت</option>
                        <option value="6">قطر</option>
                        <option value="7">أخرى</option>
                    </select>
                </td>


                <td>
                    <label> رقم المشارك </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input formControlName="participantNo" type="number">
                </td>

            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>



    <div style="text-align:right;margin:15px 15px 0px 0px">
        <button type="submit" style="width:50px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center">بحـث</button>
    </div>

    <br />




</form>
<div class="container" [hidden]="!this.participantSearchService.showParticipantSearchResult">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (keyup)="searchItems()"
                    id="search-input" mdbInput>
                <label for="search-input" style="direction:rtl">بحث</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table mdbTable #tableEl="mdbTable" stickyHeader="true" hover="true" striped="true" class="z-depth-1">
            <thead class="sticky-top">
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let head of headElements; let i = index"
                        [mdbTableSort]="this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult"
                        [sortBy]="headElements[i]" scope="col">{{head | titlecase}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody #row>
                <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult; let i = index">
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex"
                        scope="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i>
                    </td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.participantName}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.participantType}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.participantNo}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablecPagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.participantType}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.participantType}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.participantNationality}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.identificationNo}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.registrationPlace}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.participantNo}}</td>
                     <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                        {{el.ParticipantSearchResult}}</td>
                     <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex">
                          {{el.ParticipantSearchResult}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot class="grey lighten-5 w-100">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9">
                        <mdb-table-pagination [tableEl]="tableEl" paginationAlign="A"
                            [searchDataSource]="this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult">
                        </mdb-table-pagination>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my component

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, HostListener, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from 'src/app/app.service';
import { ParticipantSearchService } from './participants-search.service';
import { MdbTablePaginationComponent, MdbTableDirective } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';

@Component({
  selector: 'participants-search',
  templateUrl: './participants-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./participants-search.component.css']
})
export class ParticipantsSearchComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MdbTableDirective) mdbTable: MdbTableDirective;
  @ViewChild(MdbTablePaginationComponent) mdbTablePagination: MdbTablePaginationComponent;
  @ViewChild('row') row: ElementRef;


  headElements = ['صفحة المشاركn', 'اسم المشارك', 'رقم المشارك', 'جهة إصدار البطاقة', 'نوع المشارك', 'الجنسية', 'رقم الهوية', 'مكان التسجيل', 'تاريخ التسجيل'];

  searchText: string = '';
  previous: string;

  maxVisibleItems: number = 10;

  constructor(private appService: AppService, private participantSearchService: ParticipantSearchService,private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.appService.title = "البحث عن المشاركين";
    this.appService.showMenu = true;
    this.participantSearchService.showParticipantSearchResult = false;

    

    this.participantSearchService.AttachSearchData$.subscribe(
      () => {
        this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult);;
        this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
        this.previous = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
      }
    );

   }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult);
    
  }


  @HostListener('input') oninput() {
    this.mdbTablePagination.searchText = this.searchText;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var firstItemIndex = this.mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex;
    var lastItemIndex = this.mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex;
    console.log( this.mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex);
    this.mdbTablePagination.setMaxVisibleItemsNumberTo(this.maxVisibleItems);
    this.mdbTablePagination.calculateFirstItemIndex();
    this.mdbTablePagination.calculateLastItemIndex();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }


  searchItems() {
    const prev = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
    console.log(prev);
    this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.previous);
    if (!this.searchText) {
      this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.previous);
      this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult = this.mdbTable.getDataSource();
    }

    if (this.searchText) {
      this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult = this.mdbTable.searchLocalDataBy(this.searchText);
      this.mdbTable.setDataSource(prev);
    }
    this.mdbTablePagination.calculateFirstItemIndex();
    this.mdbTablePagination.calculateLastItemIndex();

    this.mdbTable.searchDataObservable(this.searchText).subscribe(() => {
      this.mdbTablePagination.calculateFirstItemIndex();
      this.mdbTablePagination.calculateLastItemIndex();
    });

  }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

these are easy to fix. add ngIf to tbody tag:

```
<tbody #row *ngIf="mdbTablePagination">
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. what line of the html are you getting that error?

Comment: if I comment  <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult; let i = index">
                    <td *ngIf="i+1 >= mdbTablePagination.firstItemIndex && i < mdbTablePagination.lastItemIndex"
                        scope="row">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i> does not throw the error

Comment: also add it to your .ts file ngAfterViewInit: `if(this.mdbTablePagination) {... }`

Comment: try adding it to your `<table>` tag. if mdbTablePagination doesn't exist, there's no way for it to even get to your `<tr>` tag. check your spelling.

Comment: double check what line number the error is showing up on. if coded correctly, there should be no way of reaching that line if mdbTablePagination is undefined. coded correctly it should be impossible to ever get that error.

Comment: geting another error    this.mdbTable.setDataSource(this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult); Cannot read property 'setDataSource' of undefined

Comment: same problem. you should check `if(this.mdbTable) {... }` before trying to setDataSource

Comment: you are making progress. I don't see any `@Input` statements. how is the data supposed to be getting there?

Comment: any luck getting the data

Comment: you have solved your initial error messages. now you need to figure out why your API is not working. different problem.

Comment: I am doing   ngOnInit() {
    this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult.push({id: 6, participantName: 'HH', participantNo: 12334,
            COR: 1, participantType : 1, participantNationality: 1,
            identificationNo: '23', registrationPlace: 1});
  }

Comment: I am hard coding fro now

Comment: any luck am doing ngOnInit() { this.participantSearchService.ParticipantSearchResult.push({id: 6, participantName: 'HH', participantNo: 12334, COR: 1, participantType : 1, participantNationality: 1, identificationNo: '23', registrationPlace: 1}); }